# How to plot small values

Tags: plotting

I wonder, why small values (eg. 10^-1600) would not show on a plot?

Here is a small example, where Evaluate gives a list of very small values and Plot does not show them, starting from x=20.

```
testfunc[x_] := 10^(-16 x) 
testvalues = {x -> {10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 100}};
Evaluate[testfunc[x]] /. testvalues
LogPlot[Evaluate[testfunc[x]], {x, 1, 100}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 10^-1600}]
```

[image]

I guess it has something to do with precision, but I could not find any solution for Plot function yet and would appreciate any help. Had no luck with SetPrecision/WorkingPrecision.

Comment: Interestingly, with `PlotRange -> All`, the x-axis completely disappears...

Comment: Coincidentally :), `$MinMachineNumber == 2.22507*10^-308`.  I suspect smaller numbers become `0.`

Comment: This gives the correct plot: `LogPlot[Log@testfunc[x], {x, 1, 100}, WorkingPrecision -> $MachinePrecision]`.  It **shouldn't**, but it does.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Why shouldn't it?  Using `$MachinePrecision` will result in arbitrary precision.  Perhaps you were thinking of `MachinePrecision`?  Or do I misunderstand the implication of your comment?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard  I misstated it: `LogPlot[Log@testfunc[x], {x, 1, 100}, WorkingPrecision -> $MachinePrecision]` gives the (correct) plot of `LogPlot[testfunc[x], {x, 1, 100}]` (V9.0.1, 8.0.4, 7). `Log@testfunc[x]` is **negative** over plot domain -- `LogPlot` should yield a blank graph.  Right??

Comment: Btw, it doesn't matter what the working precision is, as long as it's about `4` or more.  One can also compare with `ListLogPlot[Table[Log@testfunc[x], {x, 1, 100}]]` and `ListLogPlot[Table[testfunc[x], {x, 1, 100}]]`.  The same thing happens with other underflow functions inside `Log`, AFAICT, e.g. `LogPlot[Log[10^(-400) Sin[x]], {x, 0, 20}, 
 WorkingPrecision -> $MachinePrecision]`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hm, probably the reason why you do not get the expected result is the values of x chosen for the Plot. As most likely they are chosen as Reals (which is connected with finite MachinePrecision), all of them will be zeros.

Consider the following simplification:

```
test = Map[10^(-16 #) &, Range[10, 100, 10]];
ListLogPlot[test]`
(*
   image generated with 
     ListLogPlot[test2, 
       Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"x", "testfunc(x)"}, 
       PlotMarkers -> Automatic, Joined -> True, 
       LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, FontSize -> 12], ImageSize -> 300]
 *)
```

[image: example 1]

Here we deal with infinite precision and everything is shown on the plot.

As Michael E2 noticed in his comment, even 10.^(-16 #) would work in the code above. The reason why this would work is that Mathematica switches to arbitrary-precision when dealing with numbers that can not be expessed with machine precision. LogPlot/Plot functions do not deal with arbitrary precision though (this is just an observation though).

**Edit:**

Check the code below:

```
test2=Reap[Plot[testfunc[x], {x, 0, 100}, 
 EvaluationMonitor :> Sow[{x, testfunc[x]}]];][[-1,   1]]; 
ListLogPlot[test2]
(*Reap and Sow allow to check which points were chosen by Plot function for plotting*)
```

[image: example 2]

Here we get the proper result as we get just the calculated values.

On the other hand, the FullForm function clearly shows that Plot disregards small numbers (which in most cases is understandable).

```
FullForm[Plot[testfunc[x] // sp, {x, 0, 100}]][[1, 1, 1, -1, -1,  1, ;; 10]]

(*This prints first ten points sampled by Plot.*)
```

Comment: This works with `Map[10.^(-16 #) &, Range[10, 100, 10]]`, too, because the coordinates of `ListLogPlot` are the logarithms and *Mma* will switch to arbitrary precision numbers for higher values of `16 #`, thus avoiding underflow.

Comment: Indeed, ListLogPlot gives a proper result. Does it mean that there is no way to make Plot work with infinite precision?

Comment: Adding some pictures would enlighten your answer :)

Comment: Olga, I'd say (but I'm no expert) that since we do not have control over the sampling, it may be not possible to make LogPlot to work. I tried applying higher precision, but it failed to change anything. @Öskå, I'll do that:-).

Answer (score 4):

At some point, the plot functions make the coordinates machine-sized numbers.  At that point, numbers smaller than [`$MinMachineNumber`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/$MinMachineNumber.html) (`2.22507*10^-308` on my MacBook Pro) probably get converted to zero.  `LogPlot` and `ListLogPlot` behave differently.  It appears as if numbers less than `$MinMachineNumber`are converted to zero by`LogPlot`**before** being plugged into`Log`, whereas`ListLogPlot`takes the`Log` **first**.

Here's a workaround that allows one to use the sampling of `Plot`.  Apparently, the underflow does not interfere with `Plot's` adaptive sampling.

```
ListLogPlot[
 Transpose[{#[[1]], Exp[#[[2]]]} &@Transpose[#]] & /@ 
  Cases[Plot[Log@testfunc[x], {x, 1, 100}], Line[pts_] :> pts, Infinity],
 Joined -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

A general purpose function:

```
Options[listLogPlotFromPlot] = 
  DeleteDuplicates@Join[Options[ListLogPlot], Options[Plot]];
SetAttributes[listLogPlotFromPlot, HoldAll];

listLogPlotFromPlot[f_, domain_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] :=
 With[{plotopts = FilterRules[{opts}, Options[Plot]]},
  ListLogPlot[
   Transpose[{#[[1]], Exp[#[[2]]]} &@ Transpose[#]] & /@ 
    Cases[Plot[Log[f], domain, plotopts], Line[pts_] :> pts, Infinity],
   FilterRules[{opts}, Options[ListLogPlot]]
   ]
  ]
```

Unfortunately, separate `Lines` get styled with separate colors by `ListLogPlot`:

```
listLogPlotFromPlot[10^-400 Sin[x]^2, {x, 0, 16}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

One can fix it by supplying a `PlotStyle`.  Below we also join the points with a `Line`.

```
listLogPlotFromPlot[10^-400 Sin[x]^2, {x, 0, 16},
 Joined -> True, PlotStyle -> ColorData[1][1]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

One could also fix the coloring problem in the function `listLogPlotFromPlot`, but it seemed preferable to leave disconnected lines disconnected.  Beware, there may be problems, especially with styling, if a list of functions is used.  It would be best to generate the plots separately and combine with `Show`.