# ListPointPlot3D small and large values

Tags: plotting

I am using ListPointPlot3D for visualizing the difference between two functions. The difference sometimes can be really small on the order of 10^-50 or smaller. There is cut-off where I can not see the plot when I am doing this and that is 10^38 or 10^-38. I am aware of this ["How to plot small values"](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/52036/how-to-plot-small-values) and my $MinMachineNumber is 10^-308. Here is an example of a plot I will get out of from my calculation.

```
xcoor = Range[1, 2, 1/20];
ycoor = Range[3, 4, 1/30];
coor = Tuples[{xcoor, ycoor}];
vals2 = (x + y /. x -> xcoor) /. y -> ycoor;
vals2 = Transpose[{Flatten[vals2/10^39]}];
points = Partition[Flatten@Thread[{coor, vals2}], 3];
ListPointPlot3D[points, 
PlotRange -> {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {Min[vals2], Max[vals2]}}]
```

I even set the plot range manually but it did not help. Of course, I can always use Log10 scale and avoid this issue but I am wondering why I am seeing this at 10^-38 not 10^-400.

ps: If you change 10^39 to 10^38 you will see the points, at least that is the case for me.

Thank you

Erdem

Edit 1: I added to PlotRange option just to see if controlling it would help or not. I don't think this is a duplicate problem with [plotting small variations](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/144176/plotrange-precision-limit) because I don't see a plot points from 10^38 to 10^39.

[image]

Comment: I am not sure why this a dublicate, I can see the plot when the value is 10^38 not 10^39. I can't see any point when the value is 10^39 not a just a plane without variation like the answer you pointed out. Okay I can play with the values to "trick the plot" but that is not the problem in here.

Comment: Does my answer to the linked question solve your problem? I thought it did.

Comment: I am not sure if I am missing something in that answer but my problem is not small variations that I can't see. The values I am trying to plot are really small and of course the differences are also as small. When I subtract the mean the numbers will be even smaller. My issue is not able to see the differences in the points. I don't see any points at all. Almost like the question that I refered previously. There the numbers are really small and the variation small as well but you can see the plot.

Comment: It does not sound like you used ***my*** answer that specifically refers to your question above.  I updated it and tried to make it clearer how it can be applied.  See http://i.stack.imgur.com/mSJul.png